# Conexión entre Visual Studio 2008 y Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, configuración, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Esta es una pregunta más de configuración que de código como tal. Tengo una aplicación web, cuyo código fuente comenzó a desarrollarse con Visual Studio 2008 (Framework 2.0). Con el tiempo, se solicitó una migración de esta aplicación a Visual Studio 2010 con el Framework 4.0.

**Herramientas utilizadas:**
Visual Studio 2010, IIS (Internet Information Services) de Windows, Visual Studio 2008.

**Situación de ejemplo:**

Tengo una aplicación, dividida en dos framework distintos, 4.0 y 2.0, en vs2010 y vs2008 respectivamente, debido a una migración de la aplicación de 2.0 a 4.0 que no se llegó a finalizar. Tengo acceso al código fuente completo de la aplicación, en ambos frameworks.

Comienzo a depurar. La depuración comienza en un segmento de código que se encuentra en vs2010 (framework 4.0), pero la depuración me lleva a una pantalla de la aplicación que no se ha migrado, es decir, que se encuentra en vs2008 (framework 2.0).

La depuración no me deja seguir por encontrarse en frameworks distintos.

**Pregunta:** ¿Existe alguna forma que poder linkar vs2010 con vs2008, de tal forma que cuando tenga una situación como esta, la depuración sea capaz de encontrar los archivos de los dos frameworks y no se me detenga?

**Ejemplo:**

Tengo acceso a ambas migraciones, el código no puedo añadirlo porque es muy extenso:

```
        private List<Proc_Grid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistentes_Result> BuscaSustanciaFis()
    {
        List<Domain.Grid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistentes> sustancias = new List<Domain.Grid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistentes>();
        List<Proc_Grid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistentes_Result> result = new List<Proc_Grid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistentes_Result>();
        string nombreProducto = txtBusquedaNombreSustancia.Text.Trim();
        string nombreQuimico = txtNombreQuimico.Text.Trim();
        string formMolecular = txtFormMolecular.Text.Trim();
        string sinonimo = txtSinonimo.Text.Trim();
        string numCas = txtNumeroCas.Text.Trim();
        string numOnu = txtNumeroOnu.Text.Trim();
        string _code = string.Empty;
        string _errorFis = string.Empty;

        if (!(nombreProducto == string.Empty && nombreQuimico == string.Empty && formMolecular == string.Empty
            && sinonimo == string.Empty && numCas == string.Empty && numOnu == string.Empty))
        {
            try
            {
                sustancias.AddRange(UseCaseFactory<CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA>.Instance.BusquedaCollGridSustancia("", nombreProducto, nombreQuimico, formMolecular, sinonimo, "", numCas, numOnu, ref _code, ref _errorFis).ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

Cuando llega a la instrucción que se encuentra en en try{}, esa llamada la hace a una función que está en un fichero que no se llegó a migrar, y que se encuentra en vs2008, por lo que me lanza el siguiente error:

> No hay código fuente disponible.
>   No hay código fuente para la ubicación actual
>
> Buscando origen de 'D:\GAMA_2016\Comunes\GAMA.Business\CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA.cs'.
>   Checksum: MD5 {c9 36 fd 20 80 fe f 95 51 85 5 30 75 c0 23 76} El
>   archivo
>   'D:\GAMA_2016\Comunes\GAMA.Business\CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA.cs'
>   no existe. Buscando
>   'D:\GAMA_2016\Comunes\GAMA.Business\CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA.cs'
>   en los documentos de script... Buscando en los proyectos
>   'D:\GAMA_2016\Comunes\GAMA.Business\CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA.cs'.
>   El archivo no se encontró en un proyecto. Buscando en el directorio
>   'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.
>
> > 0\VC\crt\src\'... Buscando en el directorio 'c:\Program
> >     Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... Buscando en
> >     el directorio 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> >     10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'... Buscando en el directorio 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'... La
> >     configuración de archivos de código fuente de depuración para la
> >     solución activa indican que el depurador no pedirá que el usuario
> >     busque el archivo:
> >     D:\GAMA_2016\Comunes\GAMA.Business\CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA.cs.
> >     El depurador no puede encontrar el archivo de código fuente
> >     'D:\GAMA_2016\Comunes\GAMA.Business\CUGrid_ComunicSustDerram_SustanciaExistente_GAMA.cs'.

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al código fuente de los proyectos en ambas migraciones "2008-2010"? Creo que la respuesta dependerá al saber de qué trata tu proyecto, por favor, añade el código que te esté ocasionando problemas y la descripción del (los) error(es).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Mauricio. sí tengo acceso a ambas migraciones, el código no puedo añadirlo porque es muy extenso, vamos, se trata de trozos de 2000 y pico líneas. Voy a intentar explicar de la mejor forma posible uno de los casos en los que me sucede.

Comment: daniel, te comprendo, solo añade un fragmento de código que pueda ser el que te ocasione problemas.

Comment: ok lo pongo ya mismo sobre el EDIT de mi pregunta. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Voy a tratar de aclarar algo... VS es solo el entorno de programacion. Tu problema viene porque tienes dos proyectos compilados para diferentes frameworks, que es muy diferente al tema entornos. Que pase si abres los dos con VS2010 y ejecutas uno en 4, y el otro en 2, diciendole al de 4 que use al de 2 como objeto linkeado?

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido la solución que buscaba indagando en las opciones del Visual Studio, en el manual, y en un par de compañeros de trabajo que al parecer tuvieron que hacer algo parecido.

**¿Cómo hacer que siga la depuración?**

En el programa Visual Studio, existe una opción (que desconocía) llamada "Attach to process" o "Asociar al proceso". Para acceder ahí, voy a Debug - Attach to process.

Una vez dentro, habilito la pestaña "Show processes in all sessions" o "Mostrar los procesos de todas las sesiones"

Ordeno los procesos de forma descendente (de la Z a la A) y selecciono el proceso llamado w3wp.exe, que hace referencia al IIS y pulso Attach. Se abre un popup de advertencia, vuelvo a pulsar Attach.

En este momento ya he realizado el link entre mi vs2008 (framework 2.0) con el código vs2010 (framework 4.0), por lo que si depuro en vs2010 y me lleva la depuración a vs2008, puedo continuar pulsando F11 sin tener problemas de que no pueda abrir el fichero ni nada parecido.

**¡IMPORTANTE!** El proceso w3wp.exe aparece cuando existe un navegador abierto o el IIS está en funcionamiento. La mejor forma para comenzar con la depuración es:

1. Pongo el punto de ruptura en la línea de código que me interese depurar de vs2010 y arranco la depuración.
2. En cuanto se abra el navegador de la depuración (en la url aparecerá localhost), voy a vs2008, Debug - Attach to process y hago el attach con el proceso w3wp.exe.
3. Ya tengo mi código que se encuentra en el framework 2.0 linkado con la depuración que se ha iniciado en vs2010.

De esta forma ya no habrá problemas para depurar la aplicación, y no detendrá la depuración cuando, llegue a la parte la aplicación que se encuentra en el framework 2.0 (que era lo que me sucedía a mí).

> Esta solución es para ir desde la parte de la aplicación que está en vs2010 (4.0) a vs2008 (2.0) que es la necesidad que me ha surgido a mí. Todavía no he tenido que hacer el paso inverso (ir de 2.0 a 4.0 en la depuración).

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo varias sugerencias *las cuales iré ampliando a medida que tengamos una visión mas clara del problema*.

*Ya que tienes acceso al código fuente de los proyectos en Visual Studio 2008 y Visual Studio 2010*, yo te recomiendo:

- Modifica el código del proyecto en VS2008 para generar algún registro de errores (*escribe en un archivo de texto los errores que pueda generar el proyecto*).
- No comprendo del todo porqué hace referencia a una *clase*, por lo que te recomiendo generar una dll para que ésta la uses en tu proyecto de VS2010.